# Logitect F710 wireless range 10m max: joy limitation?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am currently the ROS joy packaging for Logitect GamePad F710 to control my robocars. However, it seems it works within 10 meters only. Is this a hardware or a ROS software problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381509/logitect-f710-wireless-range-10m-max:-joy-limitation?/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2021-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-06-30**:
Sorry to close your question, but as is it appears to not be about ROS (1 or 2) and is instead about hardware. If you can update your question to be on-topic then I'll happily reopen it for you. Otherwise, you can try out another forum that will be more appropriate for this type of question such as https://robotics.stackexchange.com/

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2021-06-30**:
I have revised it. Could you approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am currently the ROS joy packaging for Logitect GamePad F710 to control my robocars. However, it seems it works within 10 meters only. Is this a hardware or a ROS software problem?

`joy` just reads out whatever the joystick HID device reports.

Any limitations wrt distance of wireless controllers are outside its sphere of influence.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0